# how to skip the duplicate occurence of a row of data using ArrayObject in PHP?

Tags: php

am trying to print out only the unique values. since am receiving a huge object array from the I am trying to use now the ArrayObject class of PHP to iterate

```
$arrayobject = new ArrayObject($data);

$iterator = $arrayobject->getIterator();

while($iterator->valid()){
    echo $iterator->current()->USERID. " : " .$iterator->current()->SUBCATID."<br/>";
    $iterator->next();
}
```

here's the current result of that

```
201087 : 1
201146 : 1
201087 : 3
201087 : 2
```

as you can see, the first data has two other duplicates
and also, the first and second data has similar subcatid..
the objective is, print only the unique userid and subcatid..
how to skip those duplicate data, given that sample code of mine
as a starting point ?

Comment: Take a look at phps `array_unique()` function.

Comment: that didn't helped..i've tried using that several times

Comment: The combination of userid and subcatid don't have duplicates. When the userid is the same, the subcatid is different, and vice versa. What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: I'd expect that a combination of `array_unique()` and `array_flip()` can be used to reliably remove all duplicates in the key and value sets.

Comment: From the given example I don't see the advantage of using ArrayObject. $data is a plain array of objects like e.g. `$data = array(new Foo(1), new Foo(2), new Foo(99), new Foo(5));` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure I understand the question but maybe....
You can either sort the array and remember the current userid so your script can skip duplicates until it reaches another id.

```
<?php
$data = data();
usort(
    $data,
    function($a,$b) {
        return strnatcmp($a->USERID, $b->USERID);
    }
);
$current = null;
foreach( $data as $e ) {
    if ( $current!=$e->USERID ) {
        $current = $e->USERID;
        echo $e->USERID, ' ', $e->SUBCATID, "\n";
    }
}   


function data() {

    $x = array(
        array(201087,1),
        array(201146,1),
        array(201087,3),
        array(201087,2),
        array(222222,3)
    );
    foreach($x as $y) {
        $o = new StdClass;
        $o->USERID = $y[0];
        $o->SUBCATID = $y[1];
        $data[] = $o;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

or the script remembers all previously processed ids, e.g. in a hashmap/array

```
<?php
$data = data();

$processed = array();
foreach( $data as $e ) {
    if ( !isset($processed[$e->USERID]) ) {
        $processed[$e->USERID] = true;
        echo $e->USERID, ' ', $e->SUBCATID, "\n";
    }
}   


function data() {

    $x = array(
        array(201087,1),
        array(201146,1),
        array(201087,3),
        array(201087,2),
        array(222222,3)
    );
    foreach($x as $y) {
        $o = new StdClass;
        $o->USERID = $y[0];
        $o->SUBCATID = $y[1];
        $data[] = $o;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

both scripts print

```
201087 1
201146 1
222222 3
```

Comment: this one still has duplicate,,,the result should only be 201087 1 ...the 201146 1
222222 3 ..should be removed as well..or skipped and continue loooping to the $data result

Comment: @sasori Do you want to skip duplicates only while iterating? Given your example it seems that you are better of filtering the duplicates and then proceeding with other operations. Filtering can be achieved by creating an array with the key format "userid-subcatid" and populating it. Once you have iterated over all the records the new array would only contain the unique objects.

Comment: `,the result should only be 201087 1 ...the 201146 1 222222 3 ..should be removed as well` - please elaborate, I can understand why the entry `201146 1` whould be removed as well, that would mean both the user_id _and_ the subcat_id must be unique. But why the 22222,3 entry? Both "columns" are unique.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ids = array(1,2,3,4,4);
$ids = array_unique($ids); // remove duplicates
```

Comment: am dealing with objects..not just simple array you posted